# I have to click twice for copy to clipboard function to work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to Javascript. I have multiple input fields each having their own copy-to-clipboard function. The problem is if I click once it doesn't get the value I need from the particular field unless I click again. What could be the problem?

```
  const [copyNo, setCopyNo] = useState(0);
  const [copySuccess, setCopySuccess] = useState("");
  const tokenRef = useRef(null);
  const prodRef = useRef(null);
  const SandBoxRef = useRef(null);
  const SecretRef = useRef(null);
  const SandBoxSecret = useRef(null);

  function copyToClipboard(e) {
    {
      copyNo === 1 && tokenRef.current.select();
    }
    {
      copyNo === 2 && prodRef.current.select();
    }
    {
      copyNo === 3 && SecretRef.current.select();
    }
    {
      copyNo === 4 && SandBoxRef.current.select();
    }
    {
      copyNo === 5 && SandBoxSecret.current.select();
    }
    document.execCommand("copy");
    e.target.focus();
    setCopySuccess("copied");
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    {
      copyNo === 1 && tokenRef.current.select();
    }
    {
      copyNo === 2 && prodRef.current.select();
    }
    {
      copyNo === 3 && SecretRef.current.select();
    }
    {
      copyNo === 4 && SandBoxRef.current.select();
    }
    {
      copyNo === 5 && SandBoxSecret.current.select();
    }
  }, [copyNo, setCopyNo]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCopySuccess("");
    }, 2000);
  }, [copySuccess]);

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 2000);
  }, [loading]);

return (
 <Input ref={tokenRef} />
 <Button onClick={() => { setCopyNo(1);copyToClipboard();}} />

 <Input ref={prodRef} />
 <Button onClick={() => { setCopyNo(2);copyToClipboard();}} />

 <Input ref={SecretRef} />
 <Button onClick={() => { setCopyNo(3);copyToClipboard();}} />

 <Input ref={SandBoxRef} />
 <Button onClick={() => { setCopyNo(4);copyToClipboard();}} />

 <Input ref={SandBoxSecret} />
 <Button onClick={() => { setCopyNo(5);copyToClipboard();}} />
)
```

I expect it to get the value in the input field without having to click twice.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a state is an asynchronous operation. If you want your `copyToClipboard` function to have the copyNo directly, you can pass it as a parameter directly:

```
 <Input ref={tokenRef} />
 <Button onClick={() => {
     copyToClipboard(1);
    }
  } />
```

Furthermore, you need to pass the onClick event to your `copyToClipboard` function, since you use the event inside it. The the final result could be:

```
 <Input ref={tokenRef} />
 <Button onClick={(e) => {
     copyToClipboard(e,1);
    }
  } />
```

and then for the `copyToClipboard` function, you need correct syntax for the if statement as well:

```
function copyToClipboard(e,copyNo) {
    if(copyNo === 1) tokenRef.current.select();
    // and then the rest
}
```

In the end, if you paid attention, you don't need to store `copyNo` in a state variable, so you can remove it, as well as the useEffect linked to it

Comment: This didn't work @TheTisiboth

Comment: Then you could provide a minimal reproducible example,because you may have a bug somewhere else